# Hibernate: two many one to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, relationship, one-to-one

I have the three tables:
User->Profile->ProfileDetails

User have one row in the Profile table

Profile have one row in the ProfileDetails table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.User (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Profile (
  userId INT NOT NULL,
  profileData VARCHAR(45) NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.ProfileDetails (
  profileId INT NOT NULL,
  details VARCHAR(45) NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

How can I describe all these relationships in hbm.xml files, using one-to-one relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem.
I use the primary key relations:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.User (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Profile (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  profile_data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Profile_User1
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES mydb.User (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.ProfileDetails (
  profile_id INT NOT NULL,
  details INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (profile_id, details),
  INDEX fk_ProfileDetails_Profile1_idx (profile_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ProfileDetails_Profile1
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
    REFERENCES mydb.Profile (user_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and next hbm.xml mapping:

**User.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ru.myapp.User" table="User">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />

        <one-to-one name="profile" class="ru.myapp.Profile" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Profile.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ru.myapp.Profile" table="Profile">
        <id name="id" column="user_id" type="long">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">user</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="profileData" column="profile_data" type="string" />

        <one-to-one name="user" class="ru.myapp.User" />
        <one-to-one name="profileDetails" class="ru.myapp.profileDetails" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ProfileDetails.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ru.myapp.ProfileDetails" table="ProfileDetails">
        <id name="id" column="profile_id" type="long">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">profile</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="details" column="details" type="string" />

        <one-to-one name="profile" class="ru.myapp.Profile" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```